# How to create a checkerboard tile pattern in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tile, unity-editor, tilesets

I'm trying to create a checkerboard alternating tile in Unity, but creating it by hand is time-consuming and cumbersome.

I tried creating a rule tile to achieve the checkered effect, but it hasn't worked since the rule tile doesn't allow checking if the neighbor tile is of a specific type.

How can I achieve a checkerboard effect with automatic tiles to automatically place black and white tiles respectively - alternate between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Final script

If you're already familiar with all the steps how to make this work inside Unity, here's the script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using UnityEditor;

public class AlternatingTile : Tile
{
    [SerializeField] private Sprite[] tiles;
    
    public override void GetTileData(Vector3Int position, ITilemap tilemap, ref TileData tileData)
    {
        uint mask = (uint) (position.x + position.y);
        tileData.sprite = tiles[mask % 2];
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [MenuItem("Assets/Create/2D/Tiles/Alternating Tile")]
    public static void CreateAlternatingTile()
    {
        
        string path = EditorUtility.SaveFilePanelInProject(
            "Alternating Tile",
            "New Alternating Tile",
            "Asset",
            "Please enter a name for the new alternating tile",
            "Assets");

        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<AlternatingTile>(), path);
    }
#endif
}
```

#### Explanation

To create the desired checkerboard tile rule in Unity, first, create a new C# script and call it something like `AlternatingTile.cs`.

Open the script and change the base class to `Tile`.

```cs
public class AlternatingTile : Tile
```

Delete the `Start()` and `Update()` methods, because we are not using `MonoBehaviour`.

Add a class-level `Sprite[]` array for the "black and white" tiles.

```cs
[SerializeField] private Sprite[] tiles;
```

Create an `override` function for `Tile.GetFileData`.

```cs
public override void GetTileData(Vector3Int position, ITilemap tilemap, ref TileData tileData)
{
    uint mask = (uint) (position.x + position.y); // gets the absolute position of the tile
    tileData.sprite = tiles[mask % 2]; // mask = 0 or 1 depending on the absolute position of the tile
}
```

Now that we created the logic for handling which tiles to draw, let's enable Unity to create the asset for this tile.

```cs
#if UNITY_EDITOR
[MenuItem("Assets/Create/2D/Tiles/Alternating Tile")] // Where to put the menu item in menu
public static void CreateAlternatingTile()
{
    string path = EditorUtility.SaveFilePanelInProject(
            "Alternating Tile", // name of the menu
            "New Alternating Tile", // default name of the new file
            "Asset", // extension (.Asset)
            "Please enter a name for the new alternating tile", // message
            "Assets/Sprites & Tiles/Tiles"); // default folder in the project - change this to match your project!

    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<AlternatingTile>(), path);
}
#endif
```

#### Usage

If you followed the same menu item path as in the example above - in Unity Editor, click `Assets > Create > 2D > Tiles > Alternating Tile`

[image: Menu item]

Select the asset in your `Project` window, and assign the two tiles you wish to alternate.

[image: Alternating Tile in Inspector]

Drag the asset to your Tile Palette and start painting it. As you can see, the tiles are drawn in alternating pattern (checkered/checkerboard pattern).

[image: Painting the tiles]